# Android Custom Keyboard sends linked image

Tags: android, hyperlink, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

I wanted to know if it is possible to have a custom keyboard that can send images that when clicked on, sends the user to a link? A link not to the image itself but link to a specific website or so on.

Answer (score 0):

That's possible, every android application which can use inputconnection can do that, also keyboard can do that. Some keyboard support it by having own server, user upload it to their server and server sends link about it, and can submit to edit.

One example : 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sohu.inputmethod.sogou